# Move Content out of ScrollViewer.TopHeader xaml WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, z-index

I have a `ScrollViewer` which has a `TopHeader`, `TopLeftHeader` and `LeftHeader` specified.

This setup works like a charm and I have no issues here.

Problem:

I need a footer for the `ScrollViewer` which behaves exactly like the `TopHeader` but placement is at the bottom.

The only thing I could think of was to add more stuff to the header and then move it to the bottom of the page.

How much ever I raise the `zindex` of the grid which I want to place at the bottom, it still seems to be bound to the `TopHeader` and movement seems to be happening only in the `TopHeader` area.

Question:

Is it possible to move the content out of the `TopHeader` area and move it to the bottom of the `ScrollViewer`?

If so, how do I achieve this?

<s>Also, what is the maximum value of the `zindex` I can pass, since I got an `OutOfBounds` exception.</s>

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Apparently 1000000 is the upper limit to `zindex`.

Comment: Is this something just a grid with 2 rows with the scrollviewer in 0 and your footer stuff in 1 couldn't accomplish?

Comment: I tried that. Didn't seem to work.